# apache mod proxy and tomcat comet

Tags: apache, tomcat, comet, mod-proxy

I have deployed my webapp on Tomcat. It is a CometServlet.

From an apache server, I have configured mod_proxy to proxy requests to tomcat.

From my CometServlet, I have set timeout as 60 seconds.

The apache server is working fine as a proxy and sends and recieves requests from Tomcat.

But the issue is that the requests take 60 seconds to complete. So, if I make 3 ajax requests, then each request takes 60 seconds and they execute in serial. I am sure I am missing out on some configs but I am not able to figure that out.

What is it that I havent configured correctly?
Or, Should I change something else?

Thanks

Comment: Can somebody please help me out. I am now trying to figure out if apache mod proxy and comet can be used together at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping this helps others ::

I couldnt fix the issue . As a workaround, I am calling event.close everytime I send a message. This is not a scalable fix, but I am not pushing a lot of data, so it works for me.